# How to insert single quote in a table of data type nvarchar in sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a field of datatype nvarchar in sql server 2008 R2. I need to insert **Base wheel6'5"**
in to that , so i used `Txt_Specification.Text.Replace("'","''")` that not worked it inserted as **Base Wheel 6"5"** but i need it should be **Base Wheel 6'5"** how to get it

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying do it in `sql server`

Do this

```
insert into #t values('Base wheel6''5"')
```

gives

```
--Base wheel6'5"
```

`'` as `escape single quotes`

Even if you inserted like `Base wheel 6"5"`

try using [STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188043.aspx)

```
select stuff(column,patindex('%"%',column),1,'''') from #t 

--Base Wheel 6'5"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're problem lies here...

```
Txt_Specification.Text.Replace("'","''")
```

This looks like programming code to me...more specifically  C# (.NET Framework). If it is, then you don't need to escape single quotes here, just leave it as it is and then ADO.NET will do the rest for you...

```
Txt_Specification.Text;
```

Comment: You are correct its C#. but while insert it accept what it have, but while i check is it already exist in the table it not accept

Comment: @Guna I'm not too sure what you meant there

Comment: @Guna just remove the call to `Replace`

Comment: Hi Leo, before i insert i have to check is the same specification name already exist in the table, that time it shows the error the string is already closed

Comment: @Guna I still don't understand how what you're saying now relates to your question